# Asymmetric Encryption (Public-Key encryption) I need clarification

Tags: encryption, encryption-asymmetric

I have searched for HOURS on how this works and I just can't get how this can be. The only given definitions are that public keyed encrypted message can only be decrypted by private key. To me, that's just nonsense and I will explain.

A website needs to be downloaded by your browser which also means that Javascript scripts and all the other stuff are accessible to anyone that catches your website if he wishes too. This also means that now, this person knows how you calculate your stuff with your public key making it possible WITHOUT the private key to decrypt it.

I'm just trying to figure out how this works and to me it does not make sens that you CANNOT decrypt an ecrypted text from a public key when you have access to all the calculations made from the side it encrypted.

I mean, when you send a password for example, first, on YOUR end, the browser's end, it encrypts the data to be recieved by the server. By encrypting the data from the browser's end, anyone that took a look on your source code can know how you encrypted it which now can be used to decrypt it. I am creating a new encryption system for our website where the server randomly creates a session key that can only be used by the user with the corresponding session. So only the 2 computers can talk to each other with the same key so if you use the same key on another computer, it just won't work as each key is stored for each session which the key dies after a set amount of time. With what I read, this seams to be called a symetric key system. I want to try and program my own assymetric key system but in all cases when I read, I can only figure out that no matter what happens as an encryption on the client's side, if a malicious person intercepts just before sending the information, he has access to how the encryption worked and therefor, does not need the private key on the server side as he just needs to reverse the process knowing how it was done on the client's side.

I'm starting to think myself as stupid thinking that way.

I'll add a little more information as I think we don't quite catch what I mean. When sending a password, say my name "David" and let's name our user WebUser. We will name our maleficient user BadGuy. So BadGuy hapopens to integrate himself in between WebUser and his browser. BadGuy also recieves ALL javascripts of the webpage permitting him to see how the calculations work before it is sent. WebUser enters his password "David" which is submitted to the javascript encryption system. Right off the bat, BadGuy does not need to decrypot anything as he already caught the password. BUT when the website responds, BadGuy has all the calculations and can use the receieved encrypted data and decrypt it using the decryption calculations he can see in the recieved web pages code.

So the only thing I can understand is that Assymetric keys are used for encryption which technically is decryptable using public known numbers. But in cas of RSA, these 2 numbers are so large that it would take years to figure out the known decryptor. As I can also undersnat is that it is pretty much easier to create the 2 numbers from the private number. But in any case, the encryption process usually ends up with a shared temporary intimate key between the two parties for for faster commuinication and that noone can ever prevent a BagGuy between User and Browser but with todays technocolgies, the real threat is more MiTM attacks where one will sniff the network. In all cases, there is no definate way to communicate 100% of the data in a undecryptable way as at least 50% of it is decryptable i/e data coming from one side or data going to the other side.

Comment: Have you studied the mathematics behind asymmetric cryptographic systems? RSA, Diffie Hellman?  If so, what part do you not understand?

Comment: I did check everything out. Once you know the math on one side, you know how to un-math it. Any math equation can be solved when we know the initial equation. We know how they encrypted it, whatever method is used, once you have done the math, you can simply undo it. No private key is necessary once you know at it's base how it was done as all the calculations have been done and downloaded on the client's side.

Comment: I'm sorry but you are simply incorrect. You can't simply "undo" it. For example, the RSA encryption equation is `c = m^e mod n`. I generated a new (small) RSA key pair and I encrypted a message (m) using e as 65537 and I got 94737394849848593020274931110393050593716183947492. Can you tell me what `m` is if you knew `n`? How do you "undo" that?

Comment: Wty do you think downloading stuff from a public web site involves asymmetric encryption?

Comment: I do not understand why was this question down-voted. The op clearly done his research and is confused, hence he needs information. This was the reason this site was created in the first place. Also, I do not understand the close vote either, justified by the unclarity of the question. The op clearly wants to improve the safety of a website by using asymetric encryption, but does not understand how and why will that improve the safety of the site. We should not rush so much with the downvotes and close votes.

Comment: @LajosArpad: Tutorial-type questions are a poor fit for the stackoverflow Q&A format. Your answer is a good example of this, as it one of the longest answers around, barely scratches the surface of the topic, contains a subset of information that is better provided outside of SO in longer tutorials, and likely doesn't help the OP who claims to have spent time researching this subject and thus will already have read the longer tutorials.

Comment: @JamesKPolk thanks for the explanation. I think the question can be narrowed down to misunderstanding the concept of session id. My answer coped with that, but clarified what public and private keys are. Of course I did not delve too much into the details, as writing a book would take too much time and would be out of scope as well. However, even though I understand your point, I believe the question is clear. If one wants to vote for closing it, too broad seems to be a better option.

Answer (score 2):

Assymetric encryption has two keys, a public and a private key, as you correctly described, so don't feel stupid. Both keys can be used for encryption and decryption, however, if data encrypted by the public key can only be decrypted by the private key and data encrypted by the private key can only be decrypted by the public key.

As a result, in order to be successfully involved in a communication using assymetric encryption you will need to have both a public and a private key.

You share your public key with others, that is, whatever data you receive, it will be encrypted with the public key. You will subsequently be able to decrypt it using your private key, which is your secret. When you send data to the other side of the communication, you encrypt it using your private key and the other side, which has your public key will be able to decrypt it.

Consider the example of versioning. You are involved in a project with some team members. When you pull the commits of others, it is encrypted with your public key, so once it is downloaded at your end, you will be able to decrypt it via your private key. As you work and do your commits, you will push the changes into the repository, encrypted using your private key. The other side of the communication already has your public key and will be able to decrypt it. It is important that you do not share your private key with anyone, so your team-mates will not be able to impersonate you, committing malicious code in your name. You can share your public key with anyone, but it is recommended to share it only with trusted people, like your team-mates, so no one else will be able to decrypt anything encrypted by your private key.

Essentially your public key is a ridiculously large number, which is the result by multiplying two primes (private key). The two primes could be found out by prime factorization, but since the public key is a very very large number, doing the prime factorization would take such a looong time that no one will sit and wait for the time (centuries) while the factorization is being executed and the results are found out.

A session id is a value which identifies a session. If there is a single such value, then it is not an assymetric encryption, as there is no public and private key involved and once someone steals the session ID, as you correctly pointed out, the malicious third person/system can impersonate the actual user and do nasty things. So the problem you have identified actually exists, but this is not a new problem and solutions were implemented. The solution you are looking for is HTTPS. Once your site gets a proper certificate, you will be able to use assymetric encryption safe and sound. Under the hood the server will have the public key of the user's session, while the user will use the private key to encrypt/decrypt and if a middle man intercepts the public key of the session (which is not a session id), the malicious third person will not be able to impersonate the actual user. Read more here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

Comment: This is the exact definition ALL websites give which does not answer anything. Noone has been given an example of a one side only encryption using this famous equation: c = m^e mod n. I tried to follow and find example but nothing concrete to build something on it. What is "c", what is "m" what is "e" what is "n". For example, if I want to encrypt my own Name "David" I will need to gain the ascii values some day to do calculations. On the client side, when encrypting, all these are known initially to do the calculation "c, m, e and n".

Comment: @DavidRichard Read the Wikipedia article on RSA... It walks you through key generation and clearly defines what the values of `c, m, n, e, d` etc. all are. Can you ask a specific question about what you don't understand?  Help us to help you!

Comment: @DavidRichard c is the cypher text. m is the original message. n is the modulus. e is the public exponent. d is the private exponent. You really need to allocate time and look into this seriously. Your future self will thank you. I do not think I should be blamed for agreeing with the facts presented on every website. For starters, kindly watch this short video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wXB-V_Keiu8

Comment: @DavidRichard I perfectly understand your frustration, but the difference between we, who understand asymetric encryption and you, who do not understand asymetric encryption is that we have already allocated time to understand this and you did not allocate - yet. But you will have to do so.

Comment: I've spent hours figuring this out but just cannot see how this will prevent Mr BadGuy to intercept anything even with an assymetric encryption when involved right in between the user and his browser. I understand the security when Mr BadGuy is only sniffing network traffic.

Comment: @DavidRichard Assuming the attacker is passive (we don't need to get into X509 here), you should consider what the attacker actually sees.  They see `n, e` arrive from the server, so they possess `n` and `e`.  Then the client does their encryption, and sends through `c`.  To find `m`, the equation is `m = c^d mod n`.  The attacker does not possess `d`.  Therefore, the message is secure.  This is a basic overview, there are other factors like X509 certificate chains, padding, forward secrecy and asymmetric signatures.  But the basic idea is still sound.

Comment: @DavidRichard With respect, you're making it really difficult to help you since you're just repeating yourself.  Can you please clarify, specifically, why you think it **is** possible for the attacker to read messages?

Comment: I'm just wandering how an attacker positionned between the user and his browser cannot intercept the connection details when they are clear texte to beggin with and to end with.

Comment: @DavidRichard He can, he intercepts the modulus and public exponent and the encrypted message.  But he can't do anything with those things.  Does that make sense?

Comment: It half makes sens. When recieving the encrypted message, it's the browser on the user's end that decrypts it, so Mr BadGuy has what it needs to decrypt a message sent from the server. And before even beginning the encryption on the user's side, the text is passed inside a variable in the browser where anyone could intercept. So decrypting the public encrypted string is unecessary and decrypting stuf from the server can be done as the code to decrypt it is on the client's side. I'm very sorry for those annoyed by my question that seems soo rookie. I have an idea of the answer so I'l go with it

Comment: @DavidRichard `Mr BadGuy has what it needs to decrypt a message sent from the server` that's not true.. please read another answer. The idea is - during the initial channel setup a random secret key is generated known only to server and client, any listening BadGuy won't be able to calculate it. So Mr. BadGuy will see only encrypted communication and estimate amount or timing of passed data.. That's all

Comment: What I am trying to point out here is that I can agree that Mr User's data is technically undecryptable (i/e way too long to figure out) but on the other hand, if the server communicates data encrypted with it's unknown private key, what is being said is that the public key is able to decrypt what has initially been encrypted with the private key. So, in this case, any MItM (Mr BadGuy) can intercept what has been communicated with Mr User sent from the server and easily decrypt it.

Comment: @DavidRichard the server and the client are sending encrypted messages to each-other. If mr. Bad Guy is in the possession of either of the keys, then Mr. Bad Guy will be able to decrypt messages encrypted by the other key indeed. This is why neither the public, nor the private key are sent in most cases. Of course, if you will need to use the other side's public key, then you will need to receive it somehow, but you will receive it only once. Later, if someone starts to listen to your messages, Mr. Bad Guy will not be able to get any of the keys. If the message where the key itself is sent is

Comment: intercepted indeed. But again, there is no absolute safety. There are some further security measures for asynchronous encryption, for example, in the case of GPG or SSH you can even define a passphrase. In this case Mr. Bad Guy will need to know the passphrase as well in order to decrypt the messages.

Answer (score 2):

extending the previous answer

> I'm just wandering how an attacker positionned between the user and his browser cannot intercept the connection details when they are clear texte to beggin with and to end with.

The magic here is called **DH key exchange**.

The symmetric encryption key is derived using [Diffie–Hellman key exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange), where the common encryption key is exchanged.

Any "listening" party (your BadGuy) woudn't be able to derive the session key even by sniffing out the whole communications. The server will use its certificate and private key to make sure the client communicates with the legitimate target. This prevents an active "man in the middle" to pose as a false server.

> it does not make sens that you CANNOT decrypt an ecrypted text from a public key when you have access to all the calculations made from the side it encrypted.

Asymmetric cryptography is based on so called "trapdoor" funtions. It means it is easy to calculate the function one way (e.g. encrypt data), but very difficult (not feasible) to od it opposite way without some secret value (private key). Indeed sometimes it is difficult to understand it and there are a lot of constraints under the asymmetric encryption is really secure. That's why you would always use some trusted library than do it yourself.

> By encrypting the data from the browser's end, anyone that took a look on your source code can know how you encrypted it which now can be used to decrypt it.

Not without the random secret key, which is derived between the client and server during the key exchange (see the first paragraph).

> I am creating a new encryption system for our website where the server randomly creates a session key that can only be used by the user with the corresponding session.

It's one of the rules in the field of cryptography - **do not design your own crypto!**

That's usually a bad idea. Please note the currently used secure channels (SSL, TLS, .. based on [RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)), [ECC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic-curve_cryptography)) are designed, reviewed and used by a lot of smart people who know what they are doing, how to mitigate different attack vectors. And IMHO it is still not perfect, but it's the best we have.

Comment: I understand. But, they are not really clear on one thing. As I can normally understand in all occasions, the assymetric encryption is mostly used to identify the right host and communicating the next communicating symetric encryption key to make communication faster. So in all of what I have read, the assymetric encryption is only for initial handshake and to agree on a symetric encryption later.

Comment: @DavidRichard Indeed that's corect. Asymmetric encryption is used to ensure the party identity (server identity un most of the cases) and securely exchange symmetric encryption keys. Asymmetric encryption *very* performance  expensive to use it for every block of data